# Gradle sync failed: Cause: org/gradle/listener/ActionBroadcast

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Getting this error in **Android studio canary 3.0** preview while building.

Answer (score 56):

You do not need to remove the plugin, just update the version to `2.6.1`.

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.1"
}
```

You also have to add flavor dimension, check out this link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=android-studio#variant_aware

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle

Comment: There's new version 2.6.1 released, take a look please: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle

Answer (score 18):

And if you're just applying the plugin and using a classpath, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2'
```

Just change the version as defined in the classpath to:

```
classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5'
```

And then just do a gradle sync again. That's all!